# doctrine postRemove listener on delete cascade in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have the entity `File` that is on the owning side of a `oneToMany` relation, `Document` is on the inversed side. There is a cascade deletion, so when `Document` is deleted, all related `File` entities are deleted, too.

Now I have an entity listener with a `postRemove()` method for `File`. But the event is only fired, when I remove the entity directly, not when its done via cascade deletion.

Is there a solution to trigger the postRemove event with a cascade deletion?

One solution would be to put the postRemove event to Document as well, but that would not be very clean because the document should not care for the File postRemove stuff. 
Or I could replace the cascade deletion by a postRemove in Document that removes the File entities piece by piece. But I would like to keep the current cascade.

So, is there a way how I can trigger events within a cascade?

That is my current event code:

File.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\File:
    type: entity
    entityListeners:
        AppBundle\EventListener\FileListener:
            postRemove: [postRemove]
```

Listener Class

```
class FileListener {

    public function postRemove(File $file) {

        dump($file); die();           
    }
}
```

service.yml

```
file_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\FileListener
        arguments: ['%path_image%', '%path_thumb%', '%path_preview%']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity_manager: custom }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it replacing `onDelete: cascade` by `cascade: [remove]`. But `cascade: [remove]` needs to be on the inversed side! So not in File but in Document.

The downside of this solution ist, that the cascade operation is not done by the database but by doctrine itself and that means heavy memory load. Its ok for my structure with only a small collection but should be taken in mind for larger groups.